# Reference to the parent class inside a member class - include loop

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, incomplete-type

I'm building a game engine in c++ & SDL, I'm implementing a Entity Component System.
I have a class Entity which has a std::map of Components, I have a class Component, and a child class deriving from it called Apperance.
In the Component parent class I have a pointer to the parent class for getting informtion between components.
I can't include entity.h in appearance.h because entity.h includes appearance.h, and this will create an include loop which isn't legal...
Currently I'm doing `class Entity;` in the beginning of the components which works until I use the actual members of Entity which is essential.

**Code that isn't the real one but is similar:**

component.h, no errors

```cpp
class Entity;

class Component
{
    Entity* parent;

    Component(Entity* parent) : parent(parent) {}
};
```

appearance.h, has errors due to incomplete type

```cpp
#include "component.h"

class Entity;

class Appearance : public Component
{
    Appearance(Entity* parent) : Component(parent) {}
    render() { renderAt(parent->transform.position); /* Uses members of parent */ }
};
```

entity.h, no errors

```cpp
#include "component.h"
#include "appearance.h"
#include <map>

class Entity
{
private:
    std::map<int, Component> components;
public:
    Transform transform;

    Entity() {}

    void foo() { Appearance a(this); /* Uses appearance.h */ }
};
```

#### What do I do?

Comment: Move the implementation of `Appearance::render` to a source file; only declare it in the header. Same with `Entity::foo`, so you don't need to include `appearance.h` in `entity.h`

Comment: It kind of worked, the solution was indeed to move functions to the .cpp file and include the other file in it. Thanks